# Where to look up type of SQL syntax used by ArcGIS Desktop 10.x and Pro 1.x

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, arcgis-pro

I have searched all obvious resources in order to look up the type of SQL syntax used by ArcGIS Desktop (10.x) and Pro (1.x) with no luck so far; that includes Google, Wikipedia, gis.wiki.com, StackExchange, & the ESRI website. I am wondering what the specific flavor of SQL on the desktop side is (i.e. pictured below for a shp file), e.g. Microsoft, proprietary. Is this information known by users? Is there another resource I am missing?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean how does ArcGIS connect to SQL Server? ArcGIS Desktop uses the Sql Server native client: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-sql-server/connect-sqlserver.htm#

Comment: SQL used by what part of ArcGIS?  Usually it uses the SQL required by your database

Comment: Thanks to Dowlers and Midavalo for the comments. I am looking for just the attribute-table-query side of Desktop and Pro, or any other *native-to-desktop-computer* engine(s), i.e. not residing on an external server/computer. Thanks again.

Comment: Each database product has its own flavor of SQL.  Esri only has SQL flavors for shapefile and file geodatabase access -- all the others use the native RDBMS flavor.

Comment: Okay, great, thank you Vince for clarifying about shp and file geodb access; so what does that mean for the type of syntax utilized in the case of an SQL query written to select data from a shp file, i.e. is the flavor fairly generic ESRI SQL, for example?

Comment: They're not full ANSI/ISO SQL, only terse subsets.  SQL certainly isn't used to select data from a shapefile, but the attribute constraints are exposed through a SQL-like syntax.  There is no SQL engine in either shapefile or file geodatabase support, which is why you can't identify one.  Each supported SQL/NoSQL database enforces their own SQL statements.

Comment: Vince wrote: "There is no SQL engine in either shapefile or file geodatabase support, which is why you can't identify one." Perfect, that is just what I was looking for. Thank you. One final thought, where can one look that up, or find that information?

Comment: I added a screenshot and changed the wording of my question for the sake of clarity. Best

Answer (score 1):

The [ArcGIS help site](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/documentation/) has guides for using SQL within both ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro called *SQL reference for query expressions used in ArcGIS*

- [ArcGIS Desktop reference here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/sql-reference-for-query-expressions-used-in-arcgis.htm)
- [ArcGIS Pro reference here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm)

While these may be very similar (if not identical) now, I have linked to both as the ArcGIS Pro one may change over time as the product develops.

There is also a good reference for [Building a query expression](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/building-a-query-expression.htm) - also from the ArcGIS help site.